# Take Average of Quiz data using python ( Troubleshooting)

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to read in the scores from a file of students quizzes, and return the highest score out of the 3 attempts.I need to use hash/dictionary in python. Here is what I have so far.

```
STD_ID  = {}
ATTEMPTS = {}
SCORE= {}

f= open("std_attempt_score.txt", "r")
line = f.readline()
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    ents = line.split("\t")
    did = ents[1]
    if did in STD_ID:
            ATTEMPTS[did] += 3
            SCORE[did] += int(ents[2])
    else:
            STD_ID[did]  = ents[2]
            ATTEMPTS[did] = 3
            SCORE[did] = int(ents[2])


for  key in STD_ID:
    print("Avg score for Student", key, "=",SCORE)
```

Text data in file.

```
FILE
STD_ID  ATT_NUM SCORE
S23Y    1   85
S03X    1   80
S34Z    1   19
S54M    1   23
S34Z    2   25
S01X    1   79
S03X    2   10
S23Y    2   09
S34Z    3   92
S54M    2   96
S23Y    3   74
S54M    3   65
S03X    3   54
```

My results are as follows:

```
Avg score for Student 1 = {'1': 286, '2': 140, '3': 285}
Avg score for Student 2 = {'1': 286, '2': 140, '3': 285}
Avg score for Student 3 = {'1': 286, '2': 140, '3': 285}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: There a question in here?

Comment: Yes, im trying to figure out how to display the Student ID and print out the highest score out of their 3 attempts.

Comment: @MichaelMarquez are you sure that's what your input file looks like? I just tried to run this and am getting several errors

Comment: @MichaelMarquez. Some hints: (1) list indexes start at zero; (2) the attempts shouldn't be added together; (3) the average is the total-score / attempts; (4) use e.g. `SCORE[key]` to get a value from a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store the score for each attempt then why not just replace the value if it's higher than the currently recorded attempt?

```
students = {}

f = open("std_attempt_score.txt", "r")
line = f.readline()
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    ents = line.split(",")
    student_id = ents[0]
    attempt_score = int(ents[2])

    score = students.setdefault(student_id, attempt_score)

    if attempt_score > score:
        students[student_id] = attempt_score


for student_id, score in students.items():
    print("Highest score for Student", student_id, "=", score)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issues with the given code :**

Loop starts with a text header which is not checked before going to if else statements for student_id checks .Printing the same value of  `SCORE` at the end of code.no average is taken in script.

**Fixed code**

Here is a sample code

```
STD_ID  = {}
ATTEMPTS = {}
SCORE= {}

f= open("std_attempt_score.txt", "r")
line = f.readline()
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    entss = " ".join(line.split())
    ents = entss.split(" ")
    did = ents[0]
    if not line.startswith("STD_ID"): # check for the header you definitely want to skip this line
            if did in STD_ID :
                    ATTEMPTS[did] += 1
                    SCORE[did].append(int(ents[2])) #polulate student_id with marks
            else:
                    STD_ID[did] = [ents[0]] #Start Dictionary with student ID and marks
                    ATTEMPTS[did] = 1
                    SCORE[did] = [int(ents[2])]

for key in sorted(STD_ID):
    if len(SCORE[key]) < 3:
        dumValues = [0] * (3 - len(SCORE[key]))
        SCORE[key] = SCORE[key] + dumValues  # add 0's in un-attempted quizzes.
    print("Student ID {0} Score Summary : \n".format(key))
    print("Top 3 Quiz : ", sorted(SCORE[key], reverse=True)[:3])
    print("Avg score of top 3 quiz : " , sum(sorted(SCORE[key], reverse=True)[:3]) / 3)
    print("Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes : ", sorted(SCORE[key], reverse=True)[0])
    print("Total Marks in 3 Attempts : ", sum(sorted(SCORE[key], reverse=True)[:3]), "\n\n")
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Student ID S01X Score Summary : 

Top 3 Quiz :  [79, 0, 0]
Avg score of top 3 quiz :  26.333333333333332
Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes :  79
Total Marks in 3 Attempts :  79 


Student ID S03X Score Summary : 

Top 3 Quiz :  [80, 54, 10]
Avg score of top 3 quiz :  48.0
Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes :  80
Total Marks in 3 Attempts :  144 


Student ID S23Y Score Summary : 

Top 3 Quiz :  [85, 74, 9]
Avg score of top 3 quiz :  56.0
Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes :  85
Total Marks in 3 Attempts :  168 


Student ID S34Z Score Summary : 

Top 3 Quiz :  [92, 25, 19]
Avg score of top 3 quiz :  45.333333333333336
Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes :  92
Total Marks in 3 Attempts :  136 


Student ID S54M Score Summary : 

Top 3 Quiz :  [96, 65, 23]
Avg score of top 3 quiz :  61.333333333333336
Quiz With Highest Marks out of 3 Top Quizzes :  96
Total Marks in 3 Attempts :  184
```

Comment: How would I get the output to show the students ID number and print the highest score out of the the total attempts. Something like:

Comment: by total you mean total 3 attempts ? and when you say highest  you mean the sum of all 3 or one highest in 3 attempted ?

Comment: something like:                                                                                     Student S23Y = [85,80,79] Highest Score = 85                                           Student S03X = [80,10,54] Highest Score =80                                and compute the remaining students S01x,S34Z,and S54M the same way.

Comment: @MichaelMarquez please check if this is what you need and accept the ans if you have your fix :)